Tangential electric field

Given at an interface $z=0$ : $$E = (30 \hat{x} + 20 \hat{y} + 10 \hat{z})\cos(\omega t)$$
And the direction of propagation is $z$. I want to find the normal electric field $(E_N)$ and the tangential electric field $(E_t)$

I know it is obvious that $E_t = (30\hat{x} + 20\hat{y})cos(\omega t)$ and $E_N = (10\hat{z}) cos(\omega t)$
But I am confused why doesn't $E \times \hat{n}$ work?
$$(30 \hat{x} + 20 \hat{y} + 10 \hat{z}) \cos(\omega t) \times \hat{z} $$
$$= (30\hat{y} -20\hat{x}) \cos\omega t$$?
The boundary conditions say (for example) at the interface of a conductor, the tangential component of the electric field is zero and writes $$\hat{n} \times \vec{E} = 0$$
But $\hat{n} \times \vec{E}$ does not get the tangential component of E (In the above example) Why?

I would say that directly taking the normal component and taking a cross product is not equivalent. Nevertheless, if there is no normal component, the cross product should yield 0. The reason is simply, if there is a non-zero magnitude normal component, there could be infinitely many vectors that could yield $\vec{0}$ when dot product with $n$. However, if there is none, that is, the magnitude is $0$, the only possible vector is $0$, which is unique.

$A \times B = 0$ iff A and B are colinear, meaning here $E$ is colinear to $\hat{n}$ - so it is colinear to the normal of the surface, and thus doesn't have a tangential component

However, remember that $E\times \hat{n}$ is perpendicular to $E$ as well, and thus the vector is not the tan. component of $E$

@OfekGillon Yes that is exactly what I mean, it is not the tangential component of E then why references on the subject say sentences like: "The tangential components of E are equal --> E cross n = 0"

Wait I think I understood it, if someone can confirm:
It is actually that we know Et1 = Et2 (I.e. they tangential components cancel each other) and we want to express it mathematically using $E \times n = 0 $ (Which as you said means no tangential component, but won't simplify down to Et1 = Et2 right?) (I mean it implicity implies Et1-Et2 = 0 but expanding it won't get this exact equation.

A cross product should be sus, because it produces an axial vector, and setting a regular vector equal to an axial vector is "bad", unless your name rhymes with "Wu"$^1$.
So, given a normal $\hat{n}$, you have its projection operator:
$${\rm proj}_n = \hat n\hat n $$
so applying that to $\vec E$, you get, in index notation:
$$ \vec E_{\parallel} \rightarrow  (n_i n_j) E_j$$
The left-over (complement) is the vector rejection:
$$ \vec E_{\perp} = \vec E - \vec E_{\parallel} 
\rightarrow  (\delta_{ij} - n_i n_j) E_j
$$
which is very different from an operator made from the cross product, such as:
$$ E_i \rightarrow [\epsilon_{ijk}n_k] E_j $$
For completeness, you can also get the vector reflection of $\hat n$, for which there is no cute subscript, nor unambiguous single operator symbol afaik:
$${\rm Ref}^{(n)}_{ij} = \delta_{ij} - 2n_in_j $$
[1]  Beware parity violating [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wu_experiment] expressions when using the cross product
